# Scala with Cats - Cartesian + Validated

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I'm doing a simple exercise from the book `Advanced scala with cats` on my own.

I want to use `Cartesian` with `Validated`.

```scala
/*
this works
*/
type ValidatedString =  Validated[ Vector[String], String]
Cartesian[ValidatedString].product(
  "a".valid[Vector[String]],
  "b".valid[Vector[String]]
)
```

---

```scala
/* this doesnt work*/
type Result[A] = Validated[List[String], A]
Cartesian[ValidatedString].product(
    f(somevariable)//returns Result[String],
    g(somevariable)//returns Result[Int],
).map(User.tupled) // creates an user from the returned string, int
```

Im completely clueless. Any hints ?
Im getting :

`could not find implicit value for parameter instance: cats.Cartesian[Result]
    Cartesian[Result].product(
             ^`

Comment: In your first example, you define `ValidatedString` in terms of `Vector[]`, while in the second example, you define it in terms of `List[]`. Is this a real difference?

Comment: It's a minor point but your first code snippet _doesn't_ actually work, since `ValidatedString` isn't a type constructor. It would make this question more useful to future readers to make sure that your code is described correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing your imports I'd guess the issue is that you're missing a `Semigroup` instance for `List` (or `Vector`—it's not clear which you want to use), since the following works for me:

```
import cats.Cartesian, cats.data.Validated, cats.implicits._

type Result[A] = Validated[List[String], A]

Cartesian[Result].product(
  "a".valid[List[String]],
  "a".valid[List[String]]
)
```

You could replace the `cats.implicits._` part with the following:

```
import cats.instances.list._
import cats.syntax.validated._
```

…but I'd suggest starting with `cats.implicits._`.

The problem here is that `Validated` accumulates failures when you combine two instances with `product`, and what "accumulates" means in a particular context is determined by a `Semigroup` instance for the invalid type that tells you how to "add" two invalid values together.

In the case of `List` (or `Vector`), concatenation makes sense for this accumulation operation, and Cats provides the concatenation `Semigroup` for any `List[A]`, but in order to get it to be applied here you have to explicitly import it (either from `cats.implicits` or from `cats.instances.list`).